# Exclude children elements

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Given the following XML.

```
<SystemInfo ID="YY" Value="INNE">
    <NativeInfo>Data</NativeInfo>
</SystemInfo>
<SystemInfo ID="YY" Value="HUUE">
    <NativeInfo>Data</NativeInfo>
</SystemInfo>
```

Im trying to do a simple task of getting this result:

```
<SystemInfo ID="YY" Value="INNE">
</SystemInfo>
<SystemInfo ID="YY" Value="HUUE">
</SystemInfo>
```

Any ideas are most welcome. Having tried anything from using Elements(), Descendants(), and AncestorsAndSelf() without luck im turning to the community :)

Comment: You are probably selecting the element, which in turn selects its children. You need to programatically remove the children.

Comment: multiple root element in one xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can use an `XDocument`

```
XDocument doc =
    XDocument.Parse(
        @"<Root>
              <SystemInfo ID=""YY"" Value=""INNE"">
                  <NativeInfo>Data</NativeInfo>
              </SystemInfo>
              <SystemInfo ID=""YY"" Value=""HUUE"">
                <NativeInfo>Data</NativeInfo>
              </SystemInfo>
          </Root>"
        );

doc.Descendants("SystemInfo").Elements().Remove();
```

I have added a root element just for testing. After the remove, the document contains the new structure, without the removed children:

```
<Root>
  <SystemInfo ID="YY" Value="INNE" />
  <SystemInfo ID="YY" Value="HUUE" />
</Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var xmlElements = myXmlDocument.Elements("SystemInfo");

 xmlElements.ToList().ForEach(x => x.RemoveNodes());
```

Comment: Amazing feedback and response-rate. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

you can try below code :-

```
 var xDoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

                foreach (var elem in xDoc.Document.Descendants("SystemInfo"))
                {
                    elem.Descendants("NativeInfo").Remove();
                }
```

Comment: Thanks Neel, im using the suggestion from Marcel, but this is indeed similar.